# How to emit a "beep" on my computer while running a script on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, bash

I run a long script on a remote machine and I would like to hear a beep when the script ends. On my machine I can add at the end of the script:

```
echo -e '\a' > /dev/console
```

but this is not working on the remote machine which complains :

```
-bash: /dev/console: Permission denied
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep || http://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker || http://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the script by passing it as a parameter to ssh and then echo the beep locally:

```
ssh user@host /path/to/script; echo -e '\a' > /dev/console
```

Comment: it works if you add "> /dev/console" at the end of the line. 
So simple... I should have thought about it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might use `/dev/tty` instead of `/dev/console`. (I don't know how `ssh` handle beeps, so maybe you should start a terminal emulator, e.g. `ssh -X -f remotehost xterm`).